# How to start a transaction in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

`Spring 4`.

I'm working on implementing updatable cache through `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. It currently looks as follows:

```
public class MyService {

    @Setter
    private MyDao myDao;
    //Immutable
    private volatile Cache cache;

    //Static factory method
    public static MyService create(){
        MyService retVal = new MyService();
        cache = Cache.emptyCache();
        updateCache();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int get(){
         //Retrieving from cache
         return cache.getNext();
    }

    private void updateCache() {
        try{
            ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            //The runnable should be in a transaction.
            Runnable updateCache;
            //the runnable queries the MyDao,
            //which in turn currently implemented as a DB-dao
            //The cache is assigned after computation
            ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(updateCache, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Throwable t){ }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I run the runnable job in a transaction?

Annotating the `updateCache()` as `@Transactional` won't work as long as transactions are thread bound.

Comment: Don't schedule like that. Use `@Scheduled` next to the `@Transactional` and let spring handle that.

Comment: @M.Deinum _Don't schedule like that_ Is that a potentially unsafe way to update cache?

Comment: @M.Deinum Maybe you can get a sample usage in an answer?

Comment: The answer is basically to use Springs scheduling support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't schedule like that, use the [scheduling support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) of Spring.

```
public class MyService {

    @Setter
    private MyDao myDao;
    //Immutable
    private volatile Cache cache;

    //Static factory method
    public static MyService create(){
        MyService retVal = new MyService();
        cache = Cache.emptyCache();
        updateCache();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int get(){
         //Retrieving from cache
         return cache.getNext();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=60000)
    public void updateCache() {
            //the runnable queries the MyDao,
            //which in turn currently implemented as a DB-dao
            //The cache is assigned after computation
    }
}
```

Then either add `@EnableScheduling` or `<task:annotation-driven />`. See also the earlier mentioned link for more configuration options.